# Danger of criminals having your checking or savings account number

Tags: bank-account, fraud, equifax

This question is in relation to the recent Equifax breach:

I'm less concerned about my credit card number being out there. That gets stolen and used by thieves on average at least twice a year. I've never had an issue getting this reversed. I'm also not concerned with SSN so much. A credit freeze is easy enough and not planning on using my credit for at least another year.

But, what is the real danger of having your checking / savings account number in the hands of criminals? It seems to me that actual paper check fraud in recent years isn't much of a thing. What are the electronic attack vectors possible when someone has your bank account number, routing number and bank name in addition to SSN? Let's assume I've already taken the social engineering precautions and changed passwords. I'm also a human firewall and it's highly unlikely anyone will gain information from phishing attempts, phone or email scams. What are the remaining risks to Bank numbers specifically?

Comment: Just off the top of my head, they can withdraw money from your account without your consent. Essentially, they pose as you online and withdraw your money.

Comment: your checking account number is on every single check you've ever written and checking/savings accounts aren't contained on your credit report...

Comment: @Michael They can print checks that look like your checks, but I don't think they can withdraw money directly. Sites like Paypal now make two test deposits to your account (which the bad guy can't see) so it's not quite that easy. However, as quid notes, everyone you've ever written a check to has those numbers. Further, if someone wrote YOU a check, they'll have those numbers on the canceled check. Also, if they have your routing number, they automatically can get your bank name. So, I wouldn't be too worried, but keep an eye on your debits (and even credits).

Comment: @barrycarter I have set up transfers between two banks and all I need is my account number, router, and name. Then I check a box that confirms I have permission to transfer money. A scammer with that information can do the same.

Comment: @Michael Have you done this recently? The "two random deposits" system was setup explicitly to prevent that sort of thing. And, if you have done it recently, maybe let me know what bank? :)

Comment: @barrycarter A couple months ago if I remember correctly. But things could have changed

Comment: @Michael OK, wow. Can you tell me which bank let you take the money w/o making two test deposits? They may also do some sort of name confirmation or other fraud checking.

Comment: Well, if criminals have your bank account number, you risk they will send you some money... Honestly, what risk do you expect? Bank accounts are meant to be public, otherwise how any e-business would like to work?

Comment: Your credit card is used fraudulently at least twice a year? You might want to rethink how and/or where you use it. I've used cards (debit and credit) online since some time in the late 1990s (which makes it going on two decades now) and don't think I've *ever* had a fraudulent transaction.

Comment: @barrycarter I established a connection between two accounts yesterday. Two random deposits isn't a required practice to establish connection to an account.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo you can withdraw money from an account as well as send if you have the account number and bank name. It's trivially easy to determine routing numbers.

Comment: @iheanyi do you refer to direct debit? than you haven't read carefully. First it functions only in some countries (Germany for example), 2nd you must be authorized to use it. Unauthorized use of direct debit can be easily reverted and you'll be charged penalty (I'm not sure if you can be criminally prosecuted).

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo nope, not direct debit. I'm talking bank to bank transfers - essentially an electronic check. Also, no authorization required. Nobody checked whether I had permission to link the two accounts. The assumption is that having the information means it's authorized. I think you are vastly overestimating the ease of reversing such transactions. If you and I have a business relationship and have established money transfers in good faith, when one of us claims a transfer is bogus, who should the bank believe? In any case, why would criminals be deterred by the threat of prosecution?